# Blocked loading mixed active content

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl

I have enabled SSL for only specific pages. From my wishlist page if I add any product to my cart I am getting error on console as:

> Blocked loading mixed active content

There are lot of answers explains about including `JS` and `CSS`. Can some one assist me on this?

In my case `wishlist` page is having enabled `SSL` where as cart page is not. So, I am getting this error.

In the beginning I had add to wishlist URL without `https` that time also it thrown `CORS` error. So I added below,

`Mage::getUrl('', array("_secure"=>true));`

to create secure URL but now I am getting below error.

> Blocked loading mixed active content

[image]

Comment: Are you adding product to cart by AJAX ?

Comment: @AnilSuthar yes I do

Comment: Check your page url protocol (HTTP/HTTPS). All your AJAX calls must have the same protocol (HTTP/HTTPS) as your page url has.

Comment: @AnilSuthar I understood, since wishlist listing page is SSL enabled, I created add products to cart URL as `https` but this request cart action is not accepting. Review my updated question

Comment: Try to remove `http/https` from AJAX url and replace it with just `//`. For ex, if AJAX url is `http://yourhost.com/index/.........`, just use `//yourhost.com/index/.........`. This will auto detect protocols.

Comment: @AnilSuthar thanks for your response. But here my problem is not generating URL. Proper URL is being generated based on current protocol. But my request is not reached to controller

Answer (score 0):

try replace http with https in the string of the url var.

Comment: could you pls hekp me @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/212485/57334

Comment: Hi, I think the site's them needs to be checked. Could you PM me the URL, etc.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove secure from the array("_secure=>true) than It will work fine

Answer (score 0):

You will have this error in your site as long as the page does use a secure protocol whilst some content in it does not.

In short, you need to track what in your ssl page is called but yet does not use secure protocol.

--> go to your browser console and go to network tab, you will see all the calls made when your page loads and you may hover on the calls (on the column name) to see which link uses http protocol.

[image]